Why did the Hyperbola-1 have an attitude control system leak May 2022?
On May 13, 2022, the Hyperbola-1 rocket failed for the third time in a row. I could not find any launch video showing anything clearly failing. According to Seradata, the cause was an attitude control system leak. What happened that caused the leak?

"Leak"? Probably a fuel leak. Bad seal, high temperature, pressure. Some kind of complex of phenomena, I suppose.

According to Seradata:

The leak was caused by material blocking a fuel feed valve, which prevented it from sealing properly.

